# Съезжает меню при наведении

Tags: javascript, css, html5, joomla3

При наведении на меню оно съезжает то влево то вправо. Хотелось бы исправить не могу понять откуда берется стиль меню или Js или CSS. Хотя CSS весь проверил.
При наведении на long distance оно все съезжает и получается не понять что.[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
https://easy-moving.ca

Comment: Не смотрел что там и где, но могу предположить что у вас при наведении добавляются отступы, потому и всё съезжает

Comment: Не на всех пунктах меню это происходит. Смотрел CSS который выполняет это меню. В нем проблем не обнаружил

Comment: Разобрался. Надо смотреть hover. Стоял border-bottom: 1px solid #9fc9f2;
}. Не на тот класс смотрел выполнения

Comment: Теперь вопрос в другом. Я нашел стили. Исправил по фтп загрузил. Но изменения не принялись. Все изменил. В стиле тоже. В кеше тоже. А запускаю сайт изменений никаких. Но все решилось еще проще. Не забудьте очистить кэш браузера и джумлы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо смотреть hover. В Моем случае стоял `border-bottom: 1px solid #9fc9f2;`